# Qlikview, how to create an expression which does not change with listbox selection?

Tags: expression, qlikview

Example, I have table below..

```
Week, Quantity
1, 10
1, 15
1, 10
2, 20
2, 30
3, 10
3, 50
```

I also have a list box for 'Week' which is current selected on week 2.

Now, I want to create text object which shows the value of sum of quantity of week 1 (ie. 35), which will always show that result even when the list box is selected on week 2.  How can I achieve this?

Currently I managed to do an expression which sums week 1 but as soon as I select week 2 it shows 0 ....

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following to your textfield:

```
= 'Sum week 1 : ' & sum({$<Week={'1'}>}Quantity)
```

Use the '&' to concat values. And use the set analysis (Page 799 of the QlikView Reference Manual) to select the reqired values.

```
sum({$<Week={'1'}>}Quantity)
```

Read this like: Sum the values of 'Quantity' Where 'Week' is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the '$' with '1' and the expression will ignore current selection
e.g.

```
sum({1<Week={'1'}>}Quantity)
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
sum({<Week={'1'}>}Quantity)
```

That is basically telling Qlikview regardless of what is selected in Qlikview, that expression will always calculate as if Week 1 is selected.